# Switch content of DIV with another set DIVs with a timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 divs in a html page, 2 divs should be hiddent always but theire content should be displayed in another div and this content should be changed every x seconds. Hows that possible using jquery/javascript?

```
    <div id="contentA">
    <!-- Some contents goes here, and it should be hidden -->
    </div>

    <div id="contentB">
    <!-- Some contents goes here, and it should be hidden -->
    </div>        

    <div id="displayArea">
    <!-- switch between contentA and contentB on a timer say every 5 seconds -->
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use the `.html()` function to copy content from one place to another.  HTML is a *serialisation* format designed to carry DOM structures from a server to a client.  Once the page is in a DOM structure you should manipulate that DOM structure directly using DOM methods.  Using `.html()` to serialise a DOM node and then recreate it somewhere else risks losing things like event handlers, other hidden data, etc.

On that basis, to copy the current contents of a div into another:

```
var $contents = $('#contentA').contents().clone();  // copy the source element's contents
$('#displayArea').empty().append($contents);        // drop them into the destination
```

In full:

```
(function() {
    var delay = 3000;
    var state = 0;
    (function next() {
         state = 1 - state;
         var src = state ? '#contentA' : '#contentB';
         var $contents = $(src).contents().clone();
         $('#displayArea').empty().append($contents);
         setTimeout(next, delay);
    })();
 })();
```

Comment: Can you tell me if I want the first div to show say 15 seconds but the second one shows for 5 seconds what should I do?

Comment: @Sean87 put `var delay = 5000 + 10000 * state;` or similar inside the `next` function.

Comment: That's worked well! sorry to bother but I wanted to add some animation to it like show slowly, but when I change the last line before setTimeout to the following, it doesn't do anything. ` $('#displayArea').empty().append($contents).show('slow');`

Comment: @Sean87 you'll need to ensure that `#displayArea` is hidden first, ideally before the `.append()` call.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :)

```
<div id='a' style='display: none;'>this is a</div>
<div id='b' style='display: none;'>this is b</div>
<div id='show'></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var count = 0;
    var content = '';
    var j = setInterval(function () {
        count++;
        if(count%2===0){
            content = $('#a').html();
        }else{
            content = $('#b').html();
        }
        $('#show').html(content);
    }, 5000);
});
</script>
```

Comment: No, please _don't_ use `.html()` as a means to copy DOM content from one node to another - just move the nodes directly using DOM methods!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```javascript
var toggle = false;
$("#displayArea").html($("#contentA").html());

setInterval(function() {
    $("#displayArea").html(toggle ? $("#contentA").html() : $("#contentB").html());
    toggle = !toggle;
}, 5000);
```

**[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/88A9S/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use an [interval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) to trigger a function every x seconds, then jQuery [replaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) to swap the divs. If you don't want to replace the actual node but just the contents, then .html() is probably the way to go.

Comment: `replaceWith` doesn't replace _contents_, it replaces entire nodes _and_ their contents.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you need but this script should work:

```
check = true;
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        if(check) {
            check = false;
            $('#displayArea').html("a");
        }
        else {
            check = true
            $('#displayArea').html("b");
        }
    }, 5000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function doSlides() {       
   var msg = messages.shift();
   messages.push(msg);
        $('#displayArea').html(msg);    
};

var messages = [
    $('#contentA').find('p').html(),
   $('#contentB').find('p').html()
];
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/8Ux3L/

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it using setInterval():

```
var divs = $('div[id^="content"]').hide(),
    i = 0;

function cycle() {
    $("#displayArea").html(divs.eq(i).html());
    i = ++i % divs.length; // increment i, and reset to 0 when it equals divs.length
}

setInterval(cycle, 2000); //Cycle every 2 seconds
```

Wrapping in a self executing function:

```
(function cycle() {
    $("#displayArea").html(divs.eq(i).html());
    i = ++i % divs.length; // increment i, and reset to 0 when it equals divs.length

    setTimeout(cycle, 2000);
})();
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/A8WXM/)

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script>
var divSelected = "A";
function switch1()
{

if (divSelected == "A")
{
$("#displayArea").text($("#contentA").text());
divSelected  = "B";
}
else
{
$("#displayArea").text($("#contentB").text());
divSelected  = "A";
}

}

$(document).ready(function()
{
var test = setInterval( "switch1()" , 5000);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="contentA" style = "display:none;">
Contect A
    </div>

    <div id="contentB" style = "display:none;">
Content B
    </div>        

    <div id="displayArea">

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```